# Selecting the last values of a Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I am doing some basic linear algebra solving, and I'm using `np.linalg.solve()` to do so. `np.linalg.solve()` requires that `b` consist of the right side of the equation, so with an augmented matrix, the augmentation (ahem) needs to be removed. Right now the method I'm using to do that is as follows:

```
np_exercise1 = np.array([[1,5,7],[-2,-7,-5]])
a = np_exercise1.T[0:2].T
b = np_exercise1.T[2]
solution1 = np.linalg.solve(a,b)
print('x1 = {}\nx2 = {}'.format(solution1[0],solution1[1]))
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this than than a double-transpose of the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do [multidimensional indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) in numpy, where `:` selects all the data in a dimension:

```py
>>> np_exercise1[:, 0:2]
array([[ 1,  5],
       [-2, -7]])
>>> np_exercise1[:, 2]
array([ 7, -5])
```